# Java - Menu Rolável

Tags: java, window-builder

Bom dia,

Como eu faço para que o meu menu seja rolável?
Andei reinando um pouco mais não sei fazer isso no jFrame.
Alguém poderia me orientar? Muito obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia Júnior

É possivel utilizando um JScrollPane, adicione um ou mais Component(s) a ele e depois o adicione no frame que estiver usando, seja ele um JFrame ou outro.

Ex:

```
public class Exemplo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
       JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(); //component
       JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(jPanel); 
       jFrame.setContentPane(pane);
   }
}
```

Aqui é possivel encontrar outros exemplos
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#ScrollDemo